# Is there a way to use Xamarin to build Mac applications using Visual Studio?

Tags: macos, xamarin

I am looking at building a Mac application using Xamarin. But, I would prefer using Visual Studio on Windows to build this application.

Any ideas on how to go about it?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, there's no way to use Visual Studio to build Mac applications.

You can however hack something together which allows you to write code using Visual Studio:

- Copy XamMac.dll from your Mac to your Windows machine.
- Create a command line project in Visual Studio, and add all your source files as well as a reference to the XamMac.dll you copied.
- Also create a new Xamarin.Mac project in Xamarin Studio, mirroring the Visual Studio project (same source files, same references, etc).
- The above work best if you use the same files in both projects (for instance by having the files on the Windows machine, mounting the containing directory on the Mac as a file share, and then opening the file share on the Mac).

Now you can write code using Visual Studio, but you still have to build/run/test on the Mac.